# How to access MySql on Windows from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, mysql

Is it possible to have the actual MySQL database installed on Windows and access it from Ubuntu 10.10 on the local network?

I think I need a MySQL "client" ? So I looked [here (MySQL Linux0Generic)](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads), but I don't know what to download..

Ps. I tried looking for documentation on the [MySQL site](http://www.mysql.com/) but I can't see a single link for any type of documentation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can, you just need a few things set up correctly first:

- Install the MySQL [Query Browser](http://doctormo.org/install.pl?mysql-query-browser) and [Administrator](http://doctormo.org/install.pl?mysql-admin) These are both graphical tools that you can use to manage your mysql databases, no matter where they are.
- On Windows you need to make sure the machine is available over the network via a name or fixed address so your Ubuntu machine can see it correctly.
- Make sure you add permissions to access the database from non-localhost. In MySQL the default permissions are localhost only and you need to turn on the '.*' permissions for either root (if your managing it totally) or a user with the permissions you need.
- Use the MySQL Admin you installed to test the connection by attempting to log into the machine's fixed ip or name with the username and password you've set up in the permissions.

You can also use openoffice.org's database to connect to mysql databases. And it really doesn't matter that MySQL is running on Windows or Ubuntu, the concerns are the same.

Comment: You can also use openoffice base.Also you need to open MySQL port on the win box in the firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

Also in *my.cnf*

```
bind-address = server_ip_here
```

and comment:

```
 # skip-networking
```